# Mechanism of type erasure in Java

Tags: java

I've read Oracle docs on Generics, and some reference books and i still cannot grasp some of the things about Java type erasing. First of all why aren't we allowed to say :

```
public class Gen<T> {
    
    T obj = new T();

    public T getObj() {
        return obj;
    }

    public void setObj(T obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }
}
```

Why doesnt Java allow me to say new T()? I understand that memory allocation for object of type T is allocated at runtime and type erasure is done in compile time, but when the type erasure is done, all of my T's will be replaced with Objects, so why is this a big deal?

Also how is this type of manipulation with T[] possible :
T[] arr = (T[]) new Object[size];

I just cant wrap my head around this things.

Thanks in advance.

I expected for it to create Object obj = new Object(), and to give me type safety throught the code, like inserting element, or extracting it with some getter. I dont understand why is this not allowed even with type erasure?

Comment: @luk2302 Why are we then allowed to say in set method, this.obj = obj, if the type is removed? Why does Java allows that but not instance?

Comment: @luk2302 Is new T() failing becasue, after type erasure and we get to runtime, my code would be something in the sense of Object obj = new ; Empty after new because its removed? Just tryna grasp that part of the type erasure.

Comment: @luk2302 The array does care about the types; you can call `getClass` on an array or do an `instanceof` and a real `T[]` will respond differently than an `Object[]`(if `T != Object`), and you can't put objects of the wrong type into an array (though `Object[]`s think every object is the right type). It's just that *most usage* can get by with it because no one looks at the hacky bits too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All of my `T`'s will be replaced with Objects, so why is this a big deal?

Because `T` can be something other than `Object`.

```
class Gen<T> {
   public T obj;
   public Gen() { obj = new T(); /* illegal */ }
   public Gen(T t) { obj = t; /* legal */ }
   // getters and setters are unnecessary complications for this example
}

Gen<Integer> g = new Gen<Integer>();
Integer i = g.obj; // should be safe, but you would make it unsafe
i = i + 5; // uh oh

Gen<Integer> h = new Gen<Integer>(0);
Integer j = h.obj;
j = j + 5;
```

Type erasure is meant to remove generics *while keeping the program the same*, in the sense that if you ran the program without doing erasure you would get the same results. When this program is interpreted without erasure, `i` is an `Integer`. If we followed your method of type erasure, it would instead get assigned with an `Object`. So your way of doing it is wrong. Further, since `new T()` needs to know what `T` is to work, but erasure removes all runtime knowledge of `T`, there is in fact *no way* to compile `new T();` while doing erasure, so it's banned. In contrast, the non-erased and erased versions of the `h` and `j` sequence do the same operations, so those are allowed.

The thing with the array is a hack and doesn't actually create a `T[]`.

```
<T> T[] hack(int n) { return (T[])new Object[n]; }
Integer[] is = hack(5); // runtime error
```

Unchecked casts like `(T)` or `(T[])` are where Java compromises on the "same-behavior" property of erased programs. A non-erased program would fail in `hack` because the cast would fail. The erased program can't actually perform the cast, so `hack` succeeds, and the failure is in the variable assignment. As long as an incorrectly cast object is not passed anywhere where the actual type is known, nothing goes wrong. It becomes your responsibility to maintain type safety. The above function, for example, fails to do that. The following example class does it correctly.

```
class SmallLIFO<T> {
    private T[] buf = (T[])new Object[10]; // take responsibility for maintaining type safety
    private int used = 0; // the Object[]-pretending-to-be-a-T[] is never given to the user, who may know what a T is and expose the lie
    public boolean push(T t) { // this class's public interface only operates on objects that are the right type
        boolean ret = used < 10;
        if(ret) buf[used++] = t;
        return ret;
    }
    public T pop() {
        return used > 0 ? buf[--used] : null; // we'd either need a cast to (T[]) in buf or a cast to (T) here; no avoiding it
    }
}
```

Comment: so what you are saying for situation T[] obj = (T[]) new Object[size], is that even tho this is done at runtime, and T[] will be erased on both sides, this cast is still "okay" because Java always allows casting from Object to something else? And references inside my array will be of the type T or Object?

Comment: @JavaSucker201 Roughly yes. A reference to `T` *is* a reference to `Object` (but not the other way around, unless `T = Object`). An `Object[]` may contain any `Object` references, and that includes `T` references. When there is a `T` reference in an `Object[]`, it doesn't make sense to ask whether it has type `T` or `Object`. It has both types. Also, the cast is *not* "okay." It is dangerous. It is *allowed* because it useful, as long as you're careful, but whenever you see it, you should be wary of it. The compiler even gives a warning for it.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be saying that since `new T()` should all be replaced with `new Object()`, which is a perfectly valid constructor to call. Indeed this is true, but is that the intention of "`new T()`"?

The purpose of `new T()` is of course not to create a new `Object` instance, but to create a new instance of `T`, whatever that may be. And it is exactly because the JVM doesn't know what `T` is, that it is impossible to create an instance of `T`.

Suppose that Java works the way you said it would, and changed all `new T()` to `new Object()`, and you have:

```
public class Foo {
    private int x = 10;

    public Foo() { System.out.println("Hello"); }

    public static <T> T magicallyCreateT() { 
        return new T(); 
    }

    public int getX() { return x; }
}
```

What would a reasonable person expect if I did this?

```
Foo foo = Foo.magicallyCreateT();
System.out.println(foo.getX());
```

From a type-checking perspective, that snippet looks completely normal, doesn't it?

They would expect `Hello` to be printed, and `foo.getX()` to return 10, wouldn't they? But the truth is, since the `Object` constructor is called, not `Foo`'s, no `Hello` is printed, and since `magicallyCreateT` returns an instance of `Object`, you wouldn't even able to *call* `getX` on `foo`! There's no `getX` method in the `Object` class! I'd imagine the program would throw a `ClassCastException` at runtime.

So you see there are lots of problems if you just "create an `Object`", when you say "I want to create a `T`", so it is not allowed to do things like `new T()`.

For the case of `(T[])new Object[]`, it is different. You are explicitly saying that you are creating an `Object[]`, and you are casting it to `T[]`. In the same way, you can also do `(T)new Object()`. In both cases, you'd get a `ClassCastException` if something goes wrong later down the line, like the scenario above. In the same way that you can't do `new T()`, you can't do `new T[]` either!

Whenever you're casting with a type parameter like this, you're basically telling the compiler that "trust me, I know what I'm doing".